# What is Camping::Server.start invoking in /bin/camping?

Tags: ruby, camping

I'm studying how the `Camping` web framework works right now, and I don't understand what the `Camping::Server.start` at line 10 in `/bin/camping` is doing.

I expected this to call the `start` method in `/lib/camping/server.rb` at line 131, and so I put a simple `puts 'hello'` statement at the beginning of that method, expecting that statement to be invoked when I ran `/bin/camping`. However, I never saw my puts statement get called, so I can only assume that it's not that `start` method getting called.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here. Here is the link to the camping github page and the relevant sections of code:

Github: https://github.com/camping/camping

From `/bin/camping`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

$:.unshift File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../lib"

require 'camping'
require 'camping/server'

begin
   Camping::Server.start
rescue OptionParser::ParseError => ex
   puts "did it error"
   STDERR.puts "!! #{ex.message}"
   puts "** use `#{File.basename($0)} --help` for more details..."
   exit 1
end
```

From `/lib/server.rb`:

```
def start
 if options[:server] == "console"
    puts "** Starting console"
    @reloader.reload!
    r = @reloader
    eval("self", TOPLEVEL_BINDING).meta_def(:reload!) { r.reload!; nil }
    ARGV.clear
    IRB.start
    exit
 else
    name = server.name[/\w+$/]
    puts "** Starting #{name} on #{options[:Host]}:#{options[:Port]}"
    super
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My `puts 'hello'` on `Camping::Server.start` wasn't getting called because I didn't understand how static methods were defined in ruby.

`start` was being called statically, and I realize now that the `start` method I was looking at in the snippet wasn't a static method, which meant that another `start` method was getting called. I looked into `Camping::Server` and realized that it inherited from `Rack::Server`, which has the following method:

```
def self.start(options = nil)
   new(options).start
end
```

That was the method getting called, not the one on `/lib/camping/server.rb`. I had been looking at the wrong method.